# A security issue with require(send()) in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, vyper

I'm working on a uni project based on blockchain, and I have to audit our system, check known attacks, ect.
This the the document that I check, principaly, since i start to work on smart contracts issues first :
[Known-attack ethereum smart contract](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#dos-with-unexpected-revert)

I have trouble understanding the example used in the "Dos With (unexpected) revert attack" part. I share the code :

```
    // INSECURE
contract Auction {
    address currentLeader;
    uint highestBid;

    function bid() payable {
        require(msg.value > highestBid);

        require(currentLeader.send(highestBid)); // Refund the old leader, if it fails then revert

        currentLeader = msg.sender;
        highestBid = msg.value;
    }}
```

They say that an attacker could force the call of bid to revert everytime so no-one is able to bid, which would make the attacker win the auction by default.
But.. How would he do that, that's the part I don't get. Do we agree that at least this piece of contract is the "valid one", and isn't a payload ? If the payload is a contract, can anyone provide an exemple/explanation ?

I'll add that, if here I quote a solidity contract, we work with Vyper, but from what I read before, this is still a kind of issue that i'll find there too.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `send()` target address is a smart contract it will execute the [fallback function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#fallback-function).

If the `currentLeader` points to a smart contract that has a fallback function that has been intentionally made to revert on failed send, the `bid()` won't work for any participants until `currentLeader` has been changed.

[More information here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/security-review-checklist-for-a-smart-contract).

This is not a "DoS" attack but simply gotcha in Solidity programming.

Comment: I understand, so in that specific case, the contract should check whether the msg.sender address isn't the one of a smart contract before putting it as the "current leader" right ?
Also, you said it's a gotcha in solidity programming, but can't we imagine this on vyper too ?

Comment: The contract should work correctly regardless if `send()` fails or have a different design so that `send()` is not called in the context of `bid()`. EVM bytecode is the same regardless if you are using Solidity or Vyper.

Comment: Ok I think i got what i wanted, thank you for sharing your knowledge !